# can you print for loop lines next or on top of each other?

Tags: python

```py
i,a = 1,1  
for i in range(1,6):
    print(i, end = " ")
    i =+1
print()
for a in range(1,11):
    if a % 2 == False:
        print(a, end = " ")
```

I have this result:

```
              1 2 3 4 5
              2 4 6 8 10
```

I want this:

```
              1 2 3 4 5
              2 4 6 8 10
              3 6 9 12 15
              4 8 12 16 20
              5 10 15 20 25
```

As you can see I am stuck at line 3 and don't know how to progress

I tried

```py
i,a = 1,1  
for i in range(1,6):
    print(i, end = " ")
    i =+1
print()
for a in range(1,11):
    if a % 2 == False:
        print(a, end = " ")
    for b in range(3,16):
        print(b + 2, end = " ")
```

I expected this =

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
```

But I got an error.

Comment: Why don't you just keep writing more loops like your second one starting: `for a in range(1,11):`?

Comment: You want to print five rows. I suggest you begin with that. Then add another loop inside, which prints five columns.

Comment: And another hint: Note that each column of each row is a multiple of the first value in the row. And that it's a multiple of the row number.

Answer (score 4):

Use nested loops:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    for j in range(i, i * 5 + 1, i):
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()
```

The outer loop (`i`) is the first number in each row; the numbers in the row (`j`) increment by `i` until there are 5 of them in the row.  The `range` function handles all of this for you because you can tell it not only where the range `start`s and `stop`s but how much each `step` is.

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 4 6 8 10
3 6 9 12 15
4 8 12 16 20
5 10 15 20 25
```

If you want to replace 5 with another number you can do:

```
def print_times_table(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(i, i * n + 1, i):
            print(j, end=" ")
        print()

print_times_table(10)
```

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60
7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70
8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80
9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

If you want all the columns to line up nicer, try `str.ljust`:

```
def print_times_table(n):
    width = len(str(n * n))
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(i, i * n + 1, i):
            print(str(j).ljust(width), end=" ")
        print()

print_times_table(5)
```

```
1  2  3  4  5
2  4  6  8  10
3  6  9  12 15
4  8  12 16 20
5  10 15 20 25
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code gives the output you need : I want this = 1 2 3 4 5 2 4 6 8 10 3 6 9 12 15 4 8 12 16 20 5 10 15 20 25

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(1,6):
        print(i*j, end=" ")
    print("\n")
```